# making a loop with li elements

Tags: jquery, loops

I make a script. That center li img items vertical. I have this script:

```
var imageHeight = $("#main .logolint li img").height();
    var hoogteverschil = Math.floor(( 70 - imageHeight ) / 2 );
    $("#main .logolint li img").css({ marginTop: hoogteverschil });
```

But now i have a lot of li items. And this script, give every li items the same margin. How can i change this script? That the script does it for every li item?

Comment: use the jQuery .each() function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the jquery.each() property:

```
$("#main .logolint li").each(function(){
   var img = $(this).find('img');
   img.css({ marginTop: Math.floor( (70 - img.height()) / 2) });
});
```

what the .each() does is basically a for through all the jQUery collection and the $(this) points to the current li in the collection

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop:

```
$("#main .logolint li").each(function() {
    var $img = $("img", this);
    var hoogteverschil = Math.floor((70 - $img.height()) / 2);
    $img.css({ marginTop: hoogteverschil });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) function accepts a function that can be used to do this without a `each` loop:

```
$("#main .logolint li img").css('margin-top', function(){
    return Math.floor(( 70 - $(this).height() ) / 2 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use.......

```
$("#main .logolint li img").each(function(){
  $image = $("img", this);
    var hoogteverschil = Math.floor(( 70 - $image.height() ) / 2 );
    $image.css({ marginTop: hoogteverschil });
});
```